# mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize

Tags: php, c#

PHP выдает ошибку: `mcrypt_encrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize`

Что ему не нравится в векторе?

```
// Ключ
$AES_Key = "93908027539382757893442837120983";

// Вектор
$AES_IV = "33985771209830270358974938292834";

// Методы
function encrypt($string)
{
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $AES_Key, addpadding($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $AES_IV));
}

function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 32)
{
    $len = strlen($string);
    $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
    $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return $string;
}
```

Аналогичный код на шарпе работает отлично:

```
// Ключ
private const string AES_Key = "93908027539382757893442837120983";

// Вектор
private const string AES_IV = "33985771209830270358974938292834";

// Зашифровывает строку в AES CBC 256 PKCS7
internal static string AES_Encrypt(string inputStr)
{
         byte[] xBuff = null;

         using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
         {
              // Настройки
              aes.KeySize = 256;
              aes.BlockSize = 256;
              aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
              aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
              aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_Key);
              aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_IV);

              using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
              {
                  using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                  {
                       byte[] textArr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputStr);
                       cs.Write(textArr, 0, textArr.Length);
                   }

                    xBuff = ms.ToArray();
               }
          }

      return Convert.ToBase64String(xBuff);
}
```

Comment: Рискну предположить что ему не нравится длина IV: у вас это строка длиной 32 байта, а длина блока у AES только 16 байт. Почему и как именно (!) это работает в C# - черт его знает. Возможно строка урезается до размера блока

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, простой кусок кода говорит о том, что вы не правы: `$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
echo mb_strlen ($iv);` == 32 символа\байта. С вектором, сгенерированным PHP - проблем нет. Обратите внимание что используется 256 битный ключ, длина вектора должна быть `32*8=256 бит`.

Comment: Экие они затейники, прямо даже интересно что они с лишними 16 байтами IV делают в CBC...

Comment: Длина IV не зависит от длины ключа для AES, так как длина блока у AES всегда (!!!) 16 байт или 128 бит.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, задал вектор из 16 цифр - ничего не поменялось. Та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рабочий вариант:

PHP:

```
// Методы
function encrypt($message)
{
    // Ключ 
    $AES_Key256 = '28937539283712098445739080393827';

    // Вектор
    $AES_IV = '8574930392882739';

    // Алгоритм шифрования
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

    if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $AES_Key256, $AES_IV) != -1)
    {
        $cipherText = mcrypt_generic($cipher, addpadding($message));
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
        return base64_encode($cipherText);
    }
}

function addpadding($string, $blocksize = 16)
{
    $len = strlen($string);
    $pad = $blocksize - ($len % $blocksize);
    $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    return $string;
}
```

C#

```
// Ключ
private const string AES_Key = "28937539283712098445739080393827";

// Вектор
private const string AES_IV = "8574930392882739";

// Расшифровывает строку из AES 256 CBC PKCS7 из файла
internal static string AES_Decrypt(string inputStr)
{
            byte[] xBuff = null;

            using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                // Настройки
                aes.KeySize = 256;
                aes.BlockSize = 128;
                aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_Key);
                aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AES_IV);

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        byte[] textArr = Convert.FromBase64String(inputStr);
                        cs.Write(textArr, 0, textArr.Length);
                    }
                    xBuff = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(xBuff);
 }
```

Статья, необходимая для понимания принципов работы AES в PHP: https://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_aes.asp

Comment: В чем проблема-то была?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, проблем было несколько. Первая - это поля в PHP были вне зоны видимости метода. Вторая - это то, что в PHP параметр метода MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 означал не длину ключа, а длину блока, а длина ключа задается длиной параметра ключа. Что на мой взгляд крайне "неверно" (и это еще мягко сказано). В третьих - разность AES и Rijndael протокола. Согласно статье чтобы быть AES совместимым следует использовать только MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 в PHP, соответсвенно длину блока в C# я так же переделал, как и остальные параметры (длина IV и т.д.)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, и да, вы были правы насчет длины блока в AES, но не правы относительно длины блока в Rijndael. Rijndael поддерживает большую длину блока, в то время как AES поддреживает только 128 бит. Так что если вернуться к вашему вопросу о том, куда деваются вторые 16 символов\байт относительно C# - они используются, т.к. Rijndael их поддерживает в отличии от AES. В PHP же все сикось накось..